# Why am I not able to fetch data from the list, which stores data being fetched from an API, outside of the retrofit call?

Tags: java, android

So, I'm trying to fetch thumbnails (String) of some channels from youtube API using retrofit in android, and store them in a List<>.

This is how my code snippet looks like:

```
final List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

    Call<ArtistImage> artistImageCall = youtube_apiservice.getArtistThumbnail(//channel's id);
    artistImageCall.enqueue(new Callback<ArtistImage>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ArtistImage> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.d("Arist_Images", "onResponse: " + response.code());
            images.add(response.body().getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl());
            **Log.d("Artist_Image_List", "ImageUrl: " + images.get(0));**
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Artist_Images", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

And logcat is showing this:

```
D/Arist_Images: onResponse: 200
D/Artist_Image_List: ImageUrl: https://i.ytimg.com/i/Rw0x9_EfawqmgDI2IgQLLg/mq1.jpg
```

But as soon as I bring the bolded line of code

```
Log.d("Artist_Image_List", "ImageUrl: " + images.get(0));
```

out of the retrofit call, like this:

```
final List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

    Call<ArtistImage> artistImageCall = youtube_apiservice.getArtistThumbnail(//channel's id);
    artistImageCall.enqueue(new Callback<ArtistImage>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ArtistImage> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.d("Arist_Images", "onResponse: " + response.code());
            images.add(response.body().getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Artist_Images", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
**Log.d("Artist_Image_List", "ImageUrl: " + images.get(0));**
```

Logcat shows:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                  at com.example.myapplication.Browse.Browse.onCreateView(Browse.java:105)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2033)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1397)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1079)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5909)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:773)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:556)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:759)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

So, why am I not able to fetch string from the List<>, when it's called outside of the retrofit call?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using asynchronous `Call.enqueue(...)` which will complete immediately and the result in not processed yet when the log **outside** is called.

Based on your use-case you can either switch to synchronous `Call.execute()` or continue from the callback.

```
public void onResponse(Response<ArtistImage> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    for (Item item : reponse.body().getItems()) {
        images.add(item.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl());
    }

    updateUi(); // this is defined in the activity/fragment/whatever
}
```

Comment: I tried calling synchronously, but it's throwing me android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException...

Comment: And after synchronous `Call.execute()` in a new thread, it's giving me the same `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0` error

Comment: @S.Joshi `onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {}`

Comment: @S.Joshi Sorry for that. I posted the comment by mistake and can't edit it. The way to go would be to update the list in `onResponse(...)` and call function to update your interface from it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want it outside `onResponse`? The data being fetched can be only used inside `onResponse`, unless you store that fetched data into a variable and then use that variable outside `onResponse`.

```
images = response.body().getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl()); //why use 'add'?
```

Then set the adapter inside onResponse itself (as in below example)

```
List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
recyclerView.setAdapter (new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.list_item_movie, getApplicationContext()));
```

You can compare with this: www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: There are many channels' ID. I want to store each id's thumbnail in a list and pass it to a recyclerview.

Comment: Actually, That's what I'm trying to do. I'm storing response in a list, inside of the onResponse, and passing the list to the adapter outside of the retrofit call.

Comment: (Assuming you are trying to pass a list of strings fetched to the adapter)

Comment: List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
                recyclerView.setAdapter (new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.list_item_movie, getApplicationContext()));

Comment: (Above comment is an example. This one is for yours)      1. images = response.body().getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl());  //why use 'add'?  2. //set the adapter inside onResponse itself (as in above comment) You can comoare with this: www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: Okay, then how do I go if I want to get thumbnails of other channels' id? There are about 20 channels. Do I need to repeat codes for each of them?

Comment: The code I mentioned is for storing all the channel ids (if they are inside each Json object) into a list. Either post the api or post the classes too so we can have a detailed look